# navigator.userAgent to detect for mobile device?

Tags: javascript, mobile, detection

Many people use the following to detect for iPad or iPhone.

```
<script>
var agent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

var useHTML5 = (agent.indexOf('iphone')!=-1 || agent.indexOf('ipad')!=-1);

if (useHTML5){
document.write("");
} else{
document.write("");
}
</script>
```

The Apple official way to detect only for ipad iphone is

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // iPad-specific code
} else {
    // iPhone-specific code
}
```

But what if I also want to check for other mobile(at least Android devices anyways)?

Should I resort to Modernizr?
Or a script from
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ ?

Just want to add that in my particular case am using FancyBox with VideoJS.

Comment: Perhaps you should discuss what you really care about here?  Are you looking for specific capabilities you know that some mobile phones have?  Are you doing a different site design for smaller screens?  Are you trying to detect certain HTML5 capabilities?  In the end, you're much better off detecting the exact characteristics you care about (screen size, feature availability, performance characteristic, etc...) rather than a specific browser type.

Comment: And, certain browsers can change their userAgent making this useless

Answer (score 1):

MobileESP Project has a solid array of user-agent detecting methods in JavaScript too yet [MobileESP API: JavaScript](http://blog.mobileesp.com/?page_id=60) is very limited simply because some devices has no JavaScript support and a server side detection is the right way to do it. [DeviceAtlas Products](http://deviceatlas.com/products) will provide more information about the device capabilities if needed yet has its price tag too...